# Why do uninitialized class members have arbitrary values in C++?

Tags: c++

```
class test {
public:
    test() {};
    bool active;
};

int main()
{
    test a;

    cout << a.active << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The following code always prints `204`. I tested many other types, and got some very strange results. An int prints `-858993460`, a double prints `-9.25596e+61` and the list goes on.

Why doesn't C++ throw an error such as `uninitialized class member 'active' used` instead of assigning what seems to be an arbitrary value?

Comment: If you want the language to hold your hand like that, don't use C++.

Comment: C++ basically follows this principle: *You don't pay for what you don't use.* Not everyone wants or needs exceptions.

Comment: @Brian I was more interesting the explanation behind why this happens, the fact that it does doesn't bother me.

Comment: Asking questions like this isn't really sensible - it's the way the language is defined; live with it. But if you want a reason, it's because default initialisation may be expensive, and you may not want it.

Comment: @JohnLandon Exceptions are costly. And since C++ was built for speed, it doesn't force you to pay for what you don't need.

Comment: _The following code always prints 204_ I don't think that that happens.

Answer (score 0):

C++ just allocates the memory and calls the constructor.
You're free to initialize all members as you wish.

What actually happens while you're compiling in debug mode is that the compiler actually does initialize the different members to certain values that would help you understand it's uninitialized.

204 is 0xCC which is the default (microsoft?) debugger initialization value

A similar question and nice answers here: [What happens to a declared, uninitialized variable in C? Does it have a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597405/what-happens-to-a-declared-uninitialized-variable-in-c-does-it-have-a-value)